# Wiring problems for new Wi-Fi thermostat

Tags: thermostat

[image][image][image][image]I am trying to install a RTH9585wF smart color thermostat for my family room heat and A/C.

I ran a new C wire from my boiler to the thermostat yesterday and connected it to a 24 volt transformer on the outside of the boiler and to the C on the thermostat and had power no problem. I connected all the wires the same way they were on the old thermostat and for heat and A/C handler.

My problem is when I set it to call for heat, the thermostat would go off and reset itself. I called Honeywell support and they told me I need to call a technician to look at it because I have a wire coming from the air handler that goes to Rc on the thermostat and that’s where the other side of the C wire goes.

This is the current set up I am running for my old thermostat below and I don’t know if the blue wire on the air handler can be moved somewhere else or what it’s for.

[image: Thermostat wiring back plate with no wiring]
<sup>Click all images to embiggen</sup>

[image: Written docs on wiring scheme]

[image: Furnace side wiring]

current thermostat wiring:

[image: current thermostat wiring]

Could someone please help me out as I've been dealing with this for a month now?

Searching the internet has not helped. Pic below show pretty much everything all the wiring pics are air handler.

Comment: I rotated all the images to make them easier to see. I'm not sure about the last sentence - are the pics all on the "air handler", or just the last one of actual wires in a box?

Comment: why is the blue wire running from the air handler to RC on the old thermostat ? is it to power the a/C unit or is it to power the display in thermostat. They said the blue wire is causing conflict to get power from the new c wire and causing it to put to much voltage to thermostat and making it go off.

Comment: The wiring looks pretty sketchy with those exposed transformer contacts in the metal box...